# Stored Procedure Insert Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a T-SQL stored procedure that inserts into six different tables in the same database.

e.g.:

```
Declare @...variables name
declare @newid as int
declare @Identityid as int

set @newid = 0
set @Identityid = 0

begin try
begin transaction

    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1 (col1, column2)
    VALUES (col1.values, col2.values)

    SET @newid = @@IDENTITY

    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE2 (Table2_id, col1, column2)
    VALUES (@newid, col1.values, col2.values)  !--it's taking the same ID)

    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE3 (Table3_id, col1, column2)
    VALUES(@newid, col1.values, col2.values)

    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE4 (Table4_id, col1, column2)
    VALUES(@newid, col1.values, col2.values)

    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE5 (col1, column2)
    VALUES (col1.values, col2.values)

    SET @Identityid = @@IDENTITY     (!--this IdentityID will be same for
                                         next table)

    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE6 (Table6_id, col1, column2) 
    VALUES (@Identityid, col1.values, col2.values)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('ERROR',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
END
```

Now I came across a situation where I need to insert multiple records in the last two tables (`Table5` and `Table6`).

I am calling this procedure from a web service (VB.NET)

Now I am spinning my wheels trying to figure out how I can insert multiple records only to the last two tables. How can I do this?

ANSWER:

Table-valued parameters. "Table-valued parameters provide an easy way to marshal multiple rows of data from a client application to SQL Server without requiring multiple round trips or special server-side logic for processing the data. You can use table-valued parameters to encapsulate rows of data in a client application and send the data to the server in a single parameterized command. The incoming data rows are stored in a table variable that can then be operated on by using Transact-SQL"

to see and follow the steps of Table-Valued parameters [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What exactly are you asking here...?

Comment: Be careful here. You are using @@Identity to capture the inserted identity value from your insert statement. This is not always going to produce that. You should probably be using SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:Table-valued parameters.
"Table-valued parameters provide an easy way to marshal multiple rows of data from a client application to SQL Server without requiring multiple round trips or special server-side logic for processing the data. You can use table-valued parameters to encapsulate rows of data in a client application and send the data to the server in a single parameterized command. The incoming data rows are stored in a table variable that can then be operated on by using Transact-SQL"

to see and follow the steps of Table-Valued parameters [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting additional insert statements for the last two tables in your stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Tab Alleman, can you provide any simple example,i will really appreciate it if any.

Comment: You already have the code.   Just keep repeating your last 3 statements until have all the inserts you need.

Answer (score 0):

It can be acheived by the following process.

INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE5 (col1, column2)
    VALUES (col1.values, col2.values),
    (col1.values, col2.values),
    (col1.values, col2.values)

Comment: thanks but i am not hard coding those values, if so i could have done that way. but here is something different.